# Epicor 10 Custom Export from Dashboard

Tags: c#, epicorerp

I have created a Epicor Dashboard that contains a date range search and the users want to push a button for the grid data to be exported into a txt file.  I can build the txt format prior to gathering data. 
 I am having issues getting looping through the Epicor grid. I know how to load or create the txt file using C#, is there any special things i would need for Epicor to allow the code?

Ron

Comment: If this were a normal form then I would suggest looping through the EpiDataview instead of the grid. but I'm not sure if that is easily accessible in a dashboard customisation.

Comment: If i could access the EpiDataview, i could do it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing i forgot was I had to publish the dashboard and also put it on the menu. Once that was done I was able to open the dashboard in developer mode and add a customization which is where I added my new button. I added a click event for the button using the event wizard.  Then I was able to add my code which included removing two columns from printing on txt file.
Code:

```
 epiDataView edvPP =((EpiDataView)(oTrans.EpiDataViews["DataView From Grid"]));
      int Count = 0;
      int i = 0;
      using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new      System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:'Location'\Test.txt"))


{
     foreach(DataRow dr in edvPP.dataView.Table.Rows)
      {
        object[] ay = dr.ItemArray;
        for (i=0; i < Count - 1; i++)
           {
             sw.Write(ay[i].ToString() + "");
           }
         sw.WriteLine(ay[i].ToString());
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the customization window, switch to Script Editor and check the "All Code (Read only)" box. The script will then show declarations of various items accessible to your code including some Ice.Lib.Framework.BAQDataView items.

Note the name of these i.e. `V_Warehouse_1View_Row` uncheck to box and use them like this:

```
        foreach (var dataRowView in V_Warehouse_1View_Row.SelectedRows)
        {
            DoStuffWith(dataRowView);
        }
```